# Mysql C++ Driver - Get prepared statement query after created

Tags: c++, mysql, exception, driver

I use prepared statements quite heavily in my c++ application.  The problem that I'm having is that when a mysql query throws an error (i.e. foreign key constraint),

I would like to somehow be able to get that query so I can debug.
Here is a small code example from MysqlWrapper.cpp 
(A class that I have written that wraps the C++ Driver)

```
    long MysqlWrapper::Insert(sql::PreparedStatement *stmt)
    {
        try
        {
            stmt->execute();
            ...
            //return inserted id
        }
        catch(sql::SQLException &ex)
        {
            // How can I get the query being executed by stmt?
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Prepared statements are not worth the problems at MySQL, they are not much faster than classic SQL statements. They are not compiled as in other RDBMS.
I think in this case it would be better to use a batch insert instead of a prepared statement.